# Creating many objects with different materials fast with python

Tags: python, materials, keyframes

I would like to create an animation of many spheres (20000). At every keyframe I would like to assign every sphere a new colour. I manage to create the animation of the spheres with all the same material fast.
My Idea to realize this was to create 20000 materials and to assign every material to a sphere during creation of the spheres. This is absolutely slow. I also do not know why the keyframes of the color show no effect in the annimation
Here is a minimal example of what I tried:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import mathutils
import numpy as np
import os


### initial Material
print('Materialien erstellen')

mat_green = bpy.data.materials.new(name="MaterialGreen") #set new material to variable
mat_green.use_nodes = True
node_tree = mat_green.node_tree
nodes = node_tree.nodes
bsdf = nodes.get("Principled BSDF") 
bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].default_value=(0.034,0.402,0,1)


    
### Sphere to replicate

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=12, enter_editmode=False)
bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
SGreen = bpy.context.active_object
SGreen.data.materials.append(mat_green)  


maxTraces=100%%% This should be 20000 later
MaterialsCMAP=[]

print('create Materials')
for i in range(0,maxTraces):
    
    mat_CMAP = bpy.data.materials.new(name='Colormap_'+str(i).zfill(5)) #set new material to variable
    mat_CMAP.use_nodes = True
    node_tree = mat_CMAP.node_tree
    nodes = node_tree.nodes
    bsdf = nodes.get("Principled BSDF") 
    bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].default_value=(1,1,1,1)
    MaterialsCMAP.append(mat_CMAP)
    
print('create Spheres')
GreenSpheres=[]
for i in range(0,maxTraces):
    o=SGreen.copy()
    o.data.materials.append(MaterialsCMAP[i]) 
    GreenSpheres.append(o)
    
    print(str(i))

co=bpy.context.collection
frame_number=0

for o in GreenSpheres:
    co.objects.link(o)
    



particleNr=0

frame_number=1




while (particleNr <maxTraces-3):
  GreenSpheres[particleNr].location=(particleNr*50,0,0)
    mat=MaterialsCMAP[particleNr] 
    
    
    name='MyAction2_'+str(particleNr)
    mat.animation_data_create()
    mat.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions.new(name=name)

    fm_r = mat.animation_data.action.fcurves.new(data_path="diffuse_color", index=0)
    fm_g = mat.animation_data.action.fcurves.new(data_path="diffuse_color", index=1)
    fm_b = mat.animation_data.action.fcurves.new(data_path="diffuse_color", index=2)
    fm_r.keyframe_points.add(1)
    fm_g.keyframe_points.add(1)
    fm_b.keyframe_points.add(1)
    
    
    fm_r.keyframe_points[-1].co = frame_number, frame_number/50
    fm_g.keyframe_points[-1].co = frame_number, frame_number/50
    fm_b.keyframe_points[-1].co = frame_number, 1
    frame_number+=1
    
    
    particleNr +=1

bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

What could I do better? Does anyone have an idea?
That would help me alot!!!

Answer (score 0):

if you already have the velocity values maybe you could keyframe the object 'pass index', wich is an integer and does not need to be unique... this can be read later from material with a similar setup as before and lets you have a single material...

you would need to make the script keyframe this 'Pass Index' for each object, maybe go from 0 to 99 and then divide in the material and use that to pick a color... still easier than having so many materials I think

[image]

other way would be to have Blender extract somehow the velocity for you

Comment: Thank you very much, I try to understand this... do you have any idea how that could be done by script?

Comment: Is it possible to assign the color also specifically, not randomly for every object?

Comment: [here is that blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v135ua6hsoudxl8/change%20colors.blend?dl=1) if you want to check... what's the rule for color assignement? a few things can be done from the material itself... the info node > random gives you a unique value for each object in range 0-1, the color ramp could be set to return only some colors, the drived value node returns the frame number...

Comment: Thank you, I really need this to be done this by a script. And how do I get to this view, for me your file looks just like a grey cube

Comment: set the viewport shading to 'material preview' or 'rendered', the balls up in the right, or just press 'Z'... and try to explain the rule for color changes, it can be done with a script but I imagine you don't really need 20000 animated materials!

Comment: Thanks. I have 20000 spheres. My goal is to make an animation of these spheres and assign a color to these spheres depending on its speed. I need to do it with a script, because I have a dataset of spheres which I would like to display

Comment: I also thought of only taking 50 materials and change these materials for every object every frame. But I dont know how to program these keyframes

Comment: [updated the file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v135ua6hsoudxl8/change%20colors.blend?dl=1) with a little script also to show how to keyframe it... a problem I see is that ids are ints and not interpolated, so have a lot of samples but custom property would work too, and it's a bit slow to create the animation also

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which sufficces for me, thank you very much for your ideas!

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import mathutils
import numpy as np
import os





### initial Material
print('Materialien erstellen')

mat_green = bpy.data.materials.new(name="MaterialGreen") #set new material to variable
mat_green.use_nodes = True
node_tree = mat_green.node_tree
nodes = node_tree.nodes
bsdf = nodes.get("Principled BSDF") 
bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].default_value=(0.034,0.402,0,1)


    
### Sphere to replicate

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=12, enter_editmode=False)
bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
SGreen = bpy.context.active_object



maxTraces=10### This should be 20000 later
#MaterialsCMAP=[]
#for i in range(0,maxTraces):
#    mat_CMAP = bpy.data.materials.new(name='Colormap_'+str(i).zfill(5)) #set new material to variable
#    mat_CMAP.use_nodes = True
##   node_tree = mat_CMAP.node_tree
#   nodes = node_tree.nodes
#   bsdf = nodes.get("Principled BSDF") 
# #   bsdf.inputs['Base Color'].default_value=(1/(i+1),0,0,1)
#    MaterialsCMAP.append(mat_CMAP)
print('create Spheres')
GreenSpheres=[]
for i in range(0,maxTraces):
    o=SGreen.copy()
    
    
    
    GreenSpheres.append(o)
   
    
co=bpy.context.collection
frame_number=0

for o in GreenSpheres:
    co.objects.link(o)
    



particleNr=0

frame_number=1




while (particleNr <maxTraces-1):
    ob=GreenSpheres[particleNr]
    ob.location=(particleNr*50,50,50)
    name_mat='Mat_'+str(particleNr)
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name_mat)
    ob.active_material=mat
    ob.material_slots[0].link = 'OBJECT'
    ob.material_slots[0].material = mat
    nameActMat='MyActionMat_'+str(particleNr)
    nameActOb='MyAction2_'+str(particleNr)
    mat.animation_data_create()
    mat.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions.new(name=nameActMat)
    ob.animation_data_create()
    ob.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions.new(name=nameActOb)
   
    fm_g = mat.animation_data.action.fcurves.new(data_path="diffuse_color", index=1)
    fm_r = mat.animation_data.action.fcurves.new(data_path="diffuse_color", index=0)
    fm_b = mat.animation_data.action.fcurves.new(data_path="diffuse_color", index=2)
    
    fm_r.keyframe_points.add(1)
    fm_g.keyframe_points.add(1)
    fm_b.keyframe_points.add(1)
    
    
    fm_r.keyframe_points[-1].co = 1, 0
    fm_g.keyframe_points[-1].co = 1, 1
    fm_b.keyframe_points[-1].co = 1, 0
    
    fm_r.keyframe_points[-1].interpolation='CONSTANT'
    fm_g.keyframe_points[-1].interpolation='CONSTANT'
    fm_b.keyframe_points[-1].interpolation='CONSTANT'
    
    fm_r.keyframe_points.add(1)
    fm_g.keyframe_points.add(1)
    fm_b.keyframe_points.add(1)
    
    
    fm_r.keyframe_points[-1].co = frame_number, 0
    fm_g.keyframe_points[-1].co = frame_number, 0
    fm_b.keyframe_points[-1].co = frame_number, 1
    
    frame_number+=1
    
    
    particleNr +=1

bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

Comment: that's great, I wasn't too helpfull though :p